# Can a query be used to list the creators of scalar-valued functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can a query be used to list the creators of user-defined functions and stored procedures on Microsoft SQL Server? If so, how?

Assuming it's possible, I'm not sure which Catalog Views to use. I searched Google, but because the word "user" is in the search, I get mountains of unrelated results pertaining to user-defined functions in general.

Comment: This is maintained in the default trace but afaik once the default trace drops it there isn't a way to find that information anymore. The Schema Changes History report will show the objects that are still in the default trace.

Comment: Source control is your friend, as is locking down your system so that the pool of possible users is small and it isn't a mystery who created what

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you. That might work moving forward. But we have dozens of servers in our farm, and hundreds, perhaps thousands of functions to dig through and do housekeeping on (many one-offs for ETL & cleanup purposes). We'll probably have to find another way - like the classic "Whack & Wait", aka whack 'em, save 'em, & wait to see who screams.

Comment: Easier and safer to transfer them to a schema, e.g. `CREATE SCHEMA garbage;` and then `ALTER SCHEMA garbage TRANSFER dbo.WeHaveNoIdeaIfWeNeedThisFunction;` - when someone screams it is much easier to transfer that back to `dbo` than re-create, re-apply permissions, etc.

Comment: `"once the default trace drops it there isn't a way to find that information anymore."` This is not necessarily correct. In fact, [I submitted a lecture for PASS summit 2022 which include this case](https://www.facebook.com/ronen.ariely/posts/1789530991253344) (one of many cases which usually get the answer "there isn't a way to find that information"). If it will be selected then I will present it in English (I already have a recording in Hebrew from the local user group).

Comment: `"wait to see who screams"` Sometimes this is the best and simpler approach, but should be used in extremely careful. How long are going to wait for the screams? What if something is not used for a month and then someone will try and what if it will be used after a year... Just remember extremely careful, backup everything and document what you do for the sake of the next DBA

Answer (score 0):

> Can a query be used to list the creators of scalar-valued functions?

yes, but it might be very complex task.

### The simpler case: using build in default trace

When we install SQL Server then by default a default trace is created and enabled. In this case, the server logs data necessary to diagnose problems the first time they occur and this include the requested information.

You can read more about this Default Trace here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-trace-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001699

#### A short tour:

```
-- check if default trace enable
SELECT* FROM sys.configurations WHERE configuration_id = 1568
GO

-- Enable default trace:
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE; 
GO
sp_configure 'default trace enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

-- start new trace (clean trace for the sake of learning and executing demo)
Exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
Reconfigure
Exec sp_configure 'default trace', 0
Reconfigure 
Exec sp_configure 'default trace', 1
Reconfigure 
GO

-- List all traces files in the server (is_default = 1 ; active trace)
SELECT * FROM sys.traces
GO

-- Read the information (should be clean now)
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260)
SELECT @path=path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1
PRINT @path
SELECT TE.name AS EventName, DT.DatabaseName, DT.ObjectName, DT.ApplicationName, DT.LoginName,*
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable (@path,  DEFAULT) DT 
INNER JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON DT.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id 
where DatabaseID = DB_ID() and ObjectName = 'TestingByRonen'
GO

-- Do some task
drop table if exists TestingByRonen
go
create table TestingByRonen(id int)
GO

-- Read the information (new information about our task)
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260)
SELECT @path=path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1
PRINT @path
SELECT TE.name AS EventName, DT.DatabaseName, DT.ObjectName, DT.ApplicationName, DT.LoginName,*
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable (@path,  DEFAULT) DT 
INNER JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON DT.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id 
where DatabaseID = DB_ID() and ObjectName = 'TestingByRonen'
GO
```

#### The limitation

(1) Default trace might not be enabled in advance

(2) Trace might have been drops

(3) This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.

### Option 2: undocumented

All the information is well logged in the transaction log and if you kept the backup of the transaction log then even history data can be find directly from backup

For example, the following sample find Who created the database:

https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/303/SQL-Server-Who-created-the-database.aspx

Example 2: The following post presents Who deleted my record last time from the table

https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/154/SQL-Server-Who-deleted-my-record-last-time.aspx

There are tens of practical uses of parsing the transactional log file.